# CKEditor - Set default cell properties in CKEditor in Hybris Backoffice

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to set the default value of the 'Vertical Alignment' to 'Top' property present in the Cell Properties dialogbox of the CKEditor in the hybris backoffice. Such that when the user open up the dailog box the value 'Top' get automatically pre-populated in the Vertical Alignment field. (added screenshot).

[DialogBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2A6A.jpg)

I'm using the below code: (This works for setting defaults for normal textbox fields. but not working for select dropdowns).

```js
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if (dialogName === 'cellProperties') {
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        var vAlign = infoTab.get('vAlign'); //attached the screenshot of the object that I get here.
        vAlign.selectedIndex = 1; 
        infoTab.get('vAlign')['default'] = 'Top';
    }
});
```

This is the image of the vAlign object select object that i extract from the defination :
[vAlign object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd8i6.jpg)

I'm able to set the table properties like 'txtBorder', 'txtWidth'(which are texbox input) successfully, but not able to change the default in the dropdown.